# Python Alter Statement in psycopg2 not updating Peewee

Tags: python, psycopg2, peewee

Working on Postgres DB within python using pscopg2, with an ORM of pewee.  I created the initial tables using pewee and I needed to perform an ALTER statement:

```
improt psycopg2

cur.execute("ALTER TABLE Test_Table ADD COLUMN filename VARCHAR(100)")
conn.commit()
```

Which after executed, I do a select * from Test_Table from and the table is present.

However, when I do a select using the pewee ORM, that column filename does not exist in the Test_Table.

What do I need to do in order for that ALTER statement to show up using peewee?

Answer (score 0):

Peewee models are not dynamically-created based on the state of the database schema. They are declarative.

So if you are adding a column to your database, you would add a corresponding field instance to the model class. Typically this is done offline (e.g., not in the middle of while your application is running).

Refer here for docs on Peewee's schema migration utilities:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#migrate